# How to resolve jest error when attempting to run test suite?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I am receiving the following error when attempting to run a test suite using jest:

```
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined

      at Plugin.manipulateOptions (node_modules/babel-plugin-module-resolver/lib/index.js:88:9)
          at run.next (<anonymous>)
          at transform.next (<anonymous>)
```

I have attempted to resolve the issue by removing node_modules and reinstalling to no avail.

Here is a copy of my package.json which is placed in the root directory:

```
{
  "name": "obfuscate",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "test:coverage": "jest --coverage",
    "test:snapshots": "jest --updateSnapshot",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch -o",
    "serve": "node -r babel-register node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server --config config/webpack/environments/serve/index.js",
    "build:dev": "node -r babel-register node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack --config config/webpack/environments/dev/index.js",
    "build:prod": "node -r babel-register node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack --config config/webpack/environments/prod/index.js",
    "start": "npm run build:dev",
    "lint:js": "eslint \"src/**/*.js\"",
    "lint:styles": "stylelint \"src/**/*.scss\"",
    "prepush": "npm run lint:styles && npm run lint:js",
    "browsersync": "npx browser-sync start --config bs-config.js",
    "bsync": "concurrently \"npm run start \" \"npx browser-sync start --config bs-config.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.0.2",
    "babel-jest": "^22.0.4",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^2.7.1",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-async-functions": "^6.13.0",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-do-expressions": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-export-extensions": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-function-bind": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-constant-elements": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types": "^0.4.24",
    "babel-plugin-transform-regenerator": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
    "cross-env": "^5.0.5",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
    "del-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.6",
    "domready": "^1.0.8",
    "enzyme": "^3.8.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.9.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.6",
    "friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "^1.6.1",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "husky": "^0.14.3",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "img-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "jest": "^22.0.4",
    "jsdom": "^16.2.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.0.6",
    "react": "^16.8.2",
    "react-collapsible": "^2.1.0",
    "react-countup": "^4.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.2",
    "react-equalizer": "^1.3.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scroll": "^1.7.8",
    "react-slick": "^0.23.1",
    "react-spinners": "^0.3.2",
    "react-tabs": "^2.1.1",
    "react-text-mask": "^5.1.0",
    "react-transition-group": "^2.5.0",
    "react-widgets": "^4.1.2",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "sass-resources-loader": "^1.3.5",
    "standard-loader": "^6.0.1",
    "stylelint": "^8.4.0",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "^18.0.0",
    "stylelint-webpack-plugin": "^0.9.0",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.3.0",
    "url-loader": "^0.6.1",
    "webpack": "^3.6.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.13.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.2.3",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.0.0",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.2.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@obfuscate/components": "^1.0.125",
    "@obfuscate/react-ranger": "^1.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "blazy": "^1.8.2",
    "browser-sync": "^2.26.7",
    "classlist-polyfill": "^1.2.0",
    "concurrently": "^4.1.2",
    "core-js": "^3.6.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^14.1.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^3.0.3",
    "formdata-polyfill": "^3.0.19",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "js-match-height": "^1.0.7",
    "mobx": "^4.9.2",
    "mobx-react": "^5.4.3",
    "mobx-react-form": "^1.36.3",
    "nodelist-foreach-polyfill": "^1.2.0",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.3",
    "scroll-lock": "^2.1.2",
    "smoothscroll": "^0.4.0",
    "swiper": "^5.2.1",
    "url-search-params": "^1.1.0",
    "validatorjs": "^3.15.1"
  },
  "stylelint": {
    "extends": "stylelint-config-standard",
    "ignoreFiles": [
      "src/styles/vendor/**/*.scss"
    ],
    "ignoreProperties": [
      "composes"
    ],
    "rules": {
      "no-descending-specificity": null,
      "max-empty-lines": 4,
      "string-quotes": "single",
      "function-url-quotes": "always",
      "color-hex-length": "long",
      "declaration-colon-newline-after": null,
      "declaration-block-no-redundant-longhand-properties": null,
      "font-family-name-quotes": null,
      "number-leading-zero": "never",
      "value-list-comma-newline-after": null,
      "max-nesting-depth": 4,
      "selector-pseudo-element-colon-notation": "single",
      "at-rule-name-space-after": null,
      "declaration-empty-line-before": null,
      "at-rule-empty-line-before": null,
      "at-rule-no-unknown": [
        true,
        {
          "ignoreAtRules": [
            "function",
            "extend",
            "if",
            "else",
            "each",
            "mixin",
            "include",
            "return",
            "media",
            "at-root",
            "debug",
            "warn",
            "error",
            "for",
            "content"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "property-no-unknown": [
        true,
        {
          "ignoreProperties": [
            "composes"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "jest": {
    "testURL": "http://localhost",
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga|html)$": "<rootDir>config/jest/jest.filemock.js",
      "\\.(css|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    },
    "setupFiles": [
      "./config/jest/jest.setup.js"
    ],
    "modulePaths": [
      "<rootDir>/src"
    ],
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.js",
      "!src/base.js",
      "!src/index-react.js",
      "!src/index.js"
    ],
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.js?$": "babel-jest"
    },
    "verbose": true
  },
  "standard": {
    "globals": [
      "jest",
      "describe",
      "it",
      "expect",
      "shallow",
      "snapshot",
      "test",
      "enzyme",
      "mount",
      "after",
      "afterEach",
      "beforeEach",
      "parent",
      "fetch"
    ],
    "ignore": [
      "node_modules/**",
      "*.test.js"
    ],
    "parser": "babel-eslint"
  }
}
```

Here is a copy of the jest.config.js file also placed in the root directory:

```
module.exports = {
  clearMocks: true,
  coverageDirectory: "coverage",
  testURL: "http://localhost",
};
```

Here is a copy of my jest.setup.js file which is placed in config/jest:

```
import { configure } from 'enzyme'
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16'

window.matchMedia = window.matchMedia || function () {
    return {
        matches: false,
        addListener: function () { },
        removeListener: function () { }
    }
}

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved. Issue was caused by running the tests by using the "jest" command in the terminal which is different from using the npm test script which also only runs the "jest" command. The difference is the former was using a higher version of Jest which I had installed globally and ended up running into issues whereas the latter used the version of jest that corresponds with the version in the package.json.